# TypeError: "get_name()" missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, typeerror

Im creating a simple program where you can add, remove, and search for soldiers. The problem is when i want to search for a soldier, the program is pointing out that i am missing a self in the code but you dont need a self in that place. It doesen't want to find that specific soldier!

```
class Allied(army)
from Army import Army

class Allied(Army):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_country(self):
        return self.country

    def get_division(self):
        return self.division

    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}, Country: {}, Division: {}, Rank: {}".format(self.full_name, self.country, self.division, self.rank)


from Allied import Allied:

Class Baracks:

def __init__(self):
        self.axis_soldier = []
        self.allied_soldier = []

def search_for_allied_soldier(self, soldier_search):
        found_allied = []
        for soldier in self.allied_soldier:
            if soldier_search in Allied.get_name():
                found_allied.append(soldier)
                return found_allied

class BattleField:
soldier_name = input("What is the soldiers name? ")
            found_soldier = self.baracks.search_for_allied_soldier(soldier_name)
            if len(found_soldier) == 0:
                print("There is no allied soldier with that name!")
            else:
                print("Found Allied soldier")
                for soldier in found_soldier:
                    print(soldier)
```

Comment: That code is by no means valid Python :( Also please try to make a minimal failing example

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an object of `Allied`(not just import it) and then call the `get_name()`

```
obj=Allied(args)     # after creating object you can also use dir(obj) to check methods available  
obj.get_name()
```

Comment: Pls. mark the answer as correct if this resolved the issue